# Uncaught Error: Class 'Db' not found in prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

Im trying to install a module in to prestashop 1.6

When i check the phpmyadmin i saw that one table is not there.

So i go to www/modules/ecster/sq/install.php

And i get this error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Db' not found in /modules/ecsterpay/sql/install.php:45 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /modules/ecsterpay/sql/install.php on line 45
```

This is my code:

```
$sql = array();



$sql[] = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `'._DB_PREFIX_.'ecsterpay` (

    `id_cart` int(10) NOT NULL,

    `id_shop` int(10) NOT NULL,

    `key_cart` varchar(200) NOT NULL,

    `external_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\',

    `internal_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'\',

    `id_order` int(10) NOT NULL,

    `accepted` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

    `debit` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

    `annul` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

    `credit` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,



    PRIMARY KEY (`id_cart`, `id_shop`)

) ENGINE='._MYSQL_ENGINE_.' DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;';



foreach ($sql as $query) {

    if (Db::getInstance()->execute($query) == false) {

        return false;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try in install.php with : `include_once('../../../config.inc.php');`

Regards